# Transverse Html Elements Till a Specifc Attribute (id) using Jquery

Tags: html, dom, jquery

I am using Jquery 1.7.2.

I want to transverse Html Elements Till a Specifc Attribute (id) using Jquery on
mouse over on any html element in my page.

we have parents() function but problem is how to select stop on the parent element  which has id attribute

```
$("*", document.body).click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var domEl = $(this).get(0);      
      var parentEls = $(domEl).parents()
        .map(function () { 
              return this.tagName; 
            })
        .get().join(", ");
```

$("b").append("**" + parentEls + "**");
    });

this is code but i am getting all element till root 
but i want to stop on a closet elements which has attribute id in the tag

Please help me out .

Comment: It's really difficult to tell what you're *really*
 trying to do.. what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('#the-id');
```

---

Unless your'e just looking for the closest one that has any id attribute, which would be:

```
$(this).closest('[id]');
```

---

Edit: after seeing your updated question, this should be what you want:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parents = $(e.target).parentsUntil('[id]')
        .map(function() { return this.tagName; }).get().join(',');
    console.log(parents);
});
```

Note that this approach accomplishes what you want *without* selecting and binding click events to every node in the DOM, which is a pretty heavy handed approach.

---

Edit (again): looks like maybe you wanted to include the tag with the id attribute on it (the above solution is everything up to, but not including that tag).  To do this, the solution is pretty similar:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $parents = $(e.target).parentsUntil('[id]');
    var tagNames = $parents.add($parents.parent())
        .map(function() { return this.tagName; }).get().join(',');
    console.log(tagNames);
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't make his question clear. Now that he has the answer is relevant. +1

Comment: Hey Guy This is working i was searching this whole day Thanks for the help

Comment: Can u please look at the link and help me out with this  qtn.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561264/complex-css-selector-on-mouse-click-on-any-part-of-html-element-in-a-page

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to map the hierarchy from the clicked element up to the document root. In that case, you can apply [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parentEls = $(e.target).parents().map(function() { 
        return this.tagName; 
    }).get().join(", ");
});
```

Note that, as jmar777, you should also change your selector: `"*"` adds an event handler to *all* the elements, which is probably not what you want. Bind a single handler to `document` instead to take advantage of event bubbling.

Comment: i don't known where user will click or move mouse so how can we get the id is the main problem

Comment: It seems I understood your question backwards. I'll update my answer.