# Complex Css Selector on mouse Click on any Part of html Element in a Page

Tags: jquery, dom

I am using Jquery 1.7.2.
I want get output as shown below on mouse click on any html Element on web page.

Assuming Html Code is :>

```
<div id ="mySDiv" class="FT">
    <div class="product">
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#">catch</a>
        <a href="#">Throw</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This output of above code when i clicked on html element on anchor tag "catch" will be

```
DIV#mySDIV.FT DIV.product A.eq(2)
```

I am able get output till below

```
DIV#mySDIV.FT DIV.product
```

Code written to achieve the output till now

```
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $parents = $(e.target).parentsUntil('[id]');
        var tagNames = $parents.add($parents.parent())
    .map(function () {
        myCssSelector;
        var tagId = $(this).attr("id"); ;
        if (tag) {
            myCssSelector = this.tagName + "#" + tagId;
            var myClassName = $(this).attr("class");
            if (myClassName) {
                myCssSelector = myCssSelector + "." + myClassName;
            }
            else {
                myCssSelector = myCssSelector + " ";
            }
        }
        else {
            myCssSelector = this.tagName;
            var myClassName = $(this).attr("class");
            if (myClassName) {
                myCssSelector = myCssSelector + "." + myClassName;
            }
            else {
                myCssSelector = myCssSelector + " ";
            }
        }
        return myCssSelector;
    }).get().join(',');
        console.log(tagNames);
    });
```

I am not able to Transverse on the child and calculate the siblings  node of clicked element

please help me out

Comment: I have no clue what the actual question is...

Comment: i am able to transverse from the clicked element till a parent until it get a id attribute in the tag but i also want to check the clicked element's has child or not and if yes check how many siblings do it have and at what index it is present exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/earlonrails/LCUzy/9/

```
 $('*').click(function(e){
    var tagId = $(this).attr("id");    
    if (tagId) {
        myCssSelector = this.tagName + "#" + tagId;
        var myClassName = $(this).attr("class");
        if (myClassName) {
            myCssSelector = myCssSelector + "." + myClassName;
        } else {
            myCssSelector = myCssSelector + " ";
        }
    } else {
        myCssSelector = this.tagName;
        var myClassName = $(this).attr("class");
        if (myClassName) {
            myCssSelector = myCssSelector + "." + myClassName;
        } else {
            myCssSelector = myCssSelector + " " + $(this).index();
        }
    }
    console.log(myCssSelector);
});
​
```

Comment: earlonrails I am not getting  accepted output using this code.

Comment: using inspect and looking at the console. I am getting DIV#sidebar 
BODY 
HTML 
DIV.module question-stats
BODY 
HTML 
DIV.tagged
BODY 
HTML when clicking each link. Did you check the jsfiddle

Comment: yes the output u are getting can be achieve by my code too. The diffucult part is to get A.post-tag:eq(2)

Comment: Here this new version will give you the index of nested elements